# Flagging '0.0' value

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, zero

I have tried to use conditional formatting to fill any cell within a workbook red if it contains the value of `0.0`.  Excel however recognizes any blank cell as being a zero and turns them all red when going about it this way.  I have tried to use VBA code but cannot get the right combo.

Comment: Please add the code you already tired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one,

```
=and(len(a1), not(a1))
```

On a worksheet, zero equates to FALSE and anything that is not FALSE is TRUE.

Answer (score 3):

Use a formula as the rule:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),A1=0)
```

Comment: Just FYI too, in VBA you can use `IsEmpty()`.  `IsBlank()` isn't used in VBA.

Comment: FYI to your FYI - `IsEmpty()` will mostly work for that, but it's not actually what it's meant for in VBA. Important to note.

Comment: Oh really? I'll have to look in to `IsBlank` then, I thought they were equivalents.  Since you can't use `WorksheetFunction.IsBlank()`, how would you do an `IsBlank()` test in VBA? with Evaluate?

Comment: Test for `vbNullString` as the value which is effectively a pointer to `Nothing`. `IsEmpty()` is used to see if a variable has been initialized :) [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, `IsEmpty()` **will** work if the range is _truly_ empty - just pointing out that it's not _techinically_ what it was designed for, and is a common misconception in VBA

Comment: @BruceWayne Actually, only Variants can be Empty. Empty is a value that a Variant has before it has been assigned another value, but a Variant can also be assigned the Empty value at any time. All other variable types will ALWAYS fail the IsEmpty() test.

Comment: Thanks and thanks to @ExcelHero for the explanations/info!  Luckily I haven't used that too much but will need to review where I did.  Good stuff guys, thanks.

Comment: @BruceWayne The Value property of the Range object returns a Variant. That's why it works, and there is nothing wrong with testing that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IsBlank()` which will be TRUE if the cell is blank, FALSE otherwise.

Combine that with an `OR` or an `AND`, taking in your current expression testing for `0.0`, as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This will do for Conditional Formatting:

```
=(a1=0)*LEN(a1)
```

.

Here is why it works...

In the first set of parentheses we test if the current cell value is `0`. That is either TRUE or FALSE.

But this is not enough, because blank cells will also evaluate to `0`.

So, we also test if the current cell has a length. The answer to that `Some length number`.

Then, the Conditional Formatting takes the result of the calculation for each cell and applies the selected formatting when the formula evaluates to TRUE, and any numerical value other than zero is coerced to TRUE.

So, this answer's initial formula can be translated into English like so: If the current cell being evaluated has a value equivalent to zero AND that value has a length, then apply the selected Conditional Formatting.

Comment: The `LEN` function returns a number, not True/False. So I'd say it is the coercion of True/false to 1/0 that drives your solution, not a Boolean truth table

Comment: I get it now.  Forgive me, I'm a bit rusty.